# Выбор предлога в-во

Tags: предлог

Какой предлог выбрать: в или во? — 
В (во) вводной части...

Answer (score 1):

Здесь лучше "в", без наращения. Если, конечно, это не приводит к недоразумениям.

Согласно Аванесову фонетически предопреденными для варианта "во" являются лишь случаи "[вв]+согласный" (во всех вариантах смягчения и оглушения). Также не входит рассматриваемый случай в список фразеологизмов. Таким образом "во" не требуется.

Пытаться произностить три В не надо. Согласно общим положениям фонетики три согласных подряд в любом случае упрощаются до двух (или одного) звуков. Таким образом "в вводной" произносится неотличимо от просто "вводной". И именно этот факт позволяет использовать "во" в тех случаях, когда иное может вызвать двусмысленность или непонимание.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, произнося три "в" подряд, можно язык сломать, поэтому придется употребить "о" вставное

Comment: А если не произносить? В письменной речи как? Например, "в 2 классе" я точно знаю:), надо употребить предлог в, хотя просится во.

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что надо писать "в 2 классе"? "В 1 классе, в 3 классе, но во 2 классе"

Comment: Могу только развести руками!

Comment: ОK, я не права. Здесь везде надо писать во.

Comment: Почему везде? ТОлько "во втором", а все остальное с "в"

Comment: Я имела в виду свои "во" )

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае предлог В относится к слову "части". Что же получается? Во части? Думаю, всё-таки "в вводной части".

Comment: Выбор формы предлога определяется не синтаксическими отношениями, а исключительно фонетическими причинами - последовательностью произносимых звуков.